# Exibir PDF dinâmico na página com p:media Primefaces 10

Tags: java, primefaces, pdf

Após atualizar para o Primefaces 10 obtive alguns problemas.
Tenho um p:fileUpload que carrega um arquivo pdf para um StreamedContent que deveria ser exibido no componente p:media, mas ao ser carregado aparece uns caracteres estranhos como:

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 2 0 obj <</Length 49/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream x�+�r
> �26S�00SI�r � �*T0T0�B�����f������� � endstream endobj 4 0 obj
> <</Parent 3 0 R/Contents 2 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</XObject<</Xf1 1 0
> R>>/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]>>/MediaBox[0 0 595
> 842]>> endobj 6 0 obj <</Length 49/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream

Meu Bean:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.arquivoImgDoc.getInputStream(); contextoBean.setImagemDocumento(DefaultStreamedContent.builder().contentType("application/pdf").stream(() -> inputStream).build());
```

Página:

```
<p:media value="#{contextoBean.imagemDocumento}" player="pdf" cache="false" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px;" />
```

O PDF é aberto normalmente no Firefox mas no Chrome e no Edge aparece como citado acima.
Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso ou se tem alguma solução.
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVIDO:**
Eu tinha um outro método que alterava o conteúdo do PDF que estava assim:

```
contextoBean.setImagemDocumento(DefaultStreamedContent.builder().stream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(this.pg_Recadastramento_ImgDoc.getImagem())).build());
```

Eu informei o contentType no arquivo, ficando assim:

```
contextoBean.setImagemDocumento(DefaultStreamedContent.builder().contentType("application/pdf").stream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(this.pg_Recadastramento_ImgDoc.getImagem())).build());
```

E funcionou da forma que queria.